# PHPUnit Mock Object replacing Real Class

Tags: phpunit, zend-test

I have a couple of tests in my test suite being run in Zend_Test

One test creates a mock of `Foo_Bar_Baz` via PHPUnit's MockBuilder as that class its dependency.  Now in the test for `Foo_BAR_baz` (the change in case is on purpose and is necessary due to autoloading), I am not getting the class but rather an instance of the mock, which obviously doesn't work.

Doing a `var_dump` on the object results in `class Foo_Bar_Baz#27115(0) { }` so it appears to be creating an instance of the mock.

Fixing the case of in the mock gets things to work as expected.  I have never seen this behavior in mocking objects before.  For some reason the mocked class is being loaded into PHP so that when the next test tries to instantiate the real object it instantiates the mock instead.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: "I am not getting the class but rather an instance of the mock" - Can you clarify this? Your code (not the test) is instantiating an object and you're expecting it to be an instance of what exactly and you're getting what exactly?

Comment: After reading a few times maybe this will help: If you're creating a mock class and naming it after a real concrete class then you're never going to be able to get the concrete class into the internal registry.

Comment: I am able to get the concrete class with the class names the same.  It is only when they are different as in my example that it doesn't work.  And normally this works in PHPUnit except in this very strange case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names in PHP are not case-sensitive, but filenames on a *nix server are.

I suspect the change in case is causing a change in behaviour because of an autoload mechanism; PHP would only autoload one of Foo_Bar_Baz.php and Foo_BAR_Baz.php.

In your case, if you have already defined a class Foo_BAR_Baz (as a mock) then PHP will use the same definition for Foo_Bar_Baz, thereby ignoring your real class definition.