# PHPUnit can't instantiate real class after mocking

Tags: phpunit

After I mock a class in one unit test, I can not use the real class in another unit test anymore.

It is the same problem as here, but the answer isn't relevant.

[PHPUnit Mock Object replacing Real Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347417/phpunit-mock-object-replacing-real-class)

I have two unit tests:

```
class BarServiceTest {
  function setUp() {
    $this->fooService = $this->getMock('Application\Service\FooService', ['fooMethod'], [],'MockFooService', false, false, false);
  }
}
```

And:

```
class FooServiceTest {
  function setUp() {
    $this->fooService = new \Application\Service\FooService;
  }
}
```

When `FooServiceTest` runs, the `fooService` object will contain the Mock object!

How can I prevent this? Changing the `mockClassName` argument in `getMock` does change the className for the mock, but it still returns the mockObject when I try to get a real instance.

I really don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this prevents it!

```
$this->fooService = $this->getMockBuilder('Application\Service\FooService')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
```